# PHP date returns wrong number of days left to next monday

Tags: php, date

Im trying to calculate number of days left to next monday and it returns 10, Im sure its wrong, days left to next monday is 5, what im doing wrong?

```
 if (isset($_POST['entry'])) {


  $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $t_shirt=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['t-shirt']);
  $today = date("m.d.Y");
  $next_monday = date("d, m, Y", strtotime('next monday'));
  $last_monday = date("d, m, Y", strtotime('last monday'));
  $today = date("d.m.Y");


  $select_current=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entry_form WHERE email='$email'");
   if (mysql_num_rows($select_current) >= 1) {
   while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_current)) {

    $last_registered=$row['registered'];

    } 

    $diff = abs(strtotime($last_registered) - strtotime($last_monday));
    $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
    $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
    $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

    echo "$days";

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You making it to difficult for your self, already asked that question on calculating date_diff:

```
 //get today's timestamp
 $date_now = date_create("today");

 //get next monday date
 $mon_date = date_create("next monday");

 //calculate date difference
 $difference = date_diff($mon_date,$date_now);

 $int = intval($difference->format('%a'));
 echo $int;
```

Comment: @deceze , I love your comment ha ha

Comment: thank you, my challenge is how to stop users enter competition if they have already entered this week. if not they need to wait till next monday midnight

Comment: In my honest opinion you going the wrong way about it- consider this; when they enter competition regardless of the day insert record in your DB even as simple as "1" and then every time user tries to enter check if that field is ==1 then ban them, then use cronjobs or mysql event scheduler to reset all user fields to "0" at midnight every monday. That way u dont have to calculate anything!!!

Comment: I can't do that, this is a client server and im not allowed to use cron jobs, otherwise I would have written all in a django line

Comment: what DB is the client using? some ppl like to waist time, money and resources on simple tasks - just like your client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) objects like this:

```
$d = new DateTime('today');
$lm = new DateTime('last monday');
$nm = new DateTime('next monday');

echo $d->diff($lm)->format("%R%a"); // output -3
echo $d->diff($nm)->format("%R%a"); // output +4
```

This is essentially the object oriented version of [bart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23406226/2088135). The `%R` in the format specifier gives the `+` or `-` and the `%a` gives the number of days.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler way to figure out how many days to the next Monday: use `date('N')`.

> - `N`: ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0)
>     *1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)*
>
> http://php.net/date

```
$daysTillNextMonday = 7 - (date('N') - 1);
```

Comment: You can figure that out yourself, can you not? It's basic math. :o)

Comment: Nice. It might make it clearer to show `date('N', strtotime('next monday'))` instead of the `1`.